# How to reduce error-message spam in visual studio when an unhandled exception occurs while debugging in Visual Studio (.NET6 web application)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

When an unhandled exception occurs in let's say a controller, every time I press 'Continue' to continue debugging, every middleware's `await next(context)` throws the error that occurred in the controller.

My question is whether it's possible to avoid having to press 'Continue' for every middleware that's been called before the controller in question.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Within the VS Exception Settings window you can configure when a break should happen for each exception type. I normally have this window open in a debug session and if I need to debug a specific exception I normally enable the check at *Common Language Runtime Exceptions*. When the exception gets thrown the debugger breaks and I can inspect what is needed. Now pressing F5 could lead to an endless session of pressing F5 again and again.

To avoid this, restore the default exception settings by pressing the most right toolbar icon or remove the check entirely. If you press F5 now, the debugger won't break anymore on handled exceptions.

[image: VS Exception Settings window]

Comment: This only changes the global settings right? The exception that occurs quite often while debugging new code is a null reference. This seems to be returned to the middleware and just keeps going through each one throwing the error-dialog in Visual Studio. I've updated my question with more info.

Comment: Yes, there is only this global settings. AFAIK all you can do is flipping the check box at the right point in time. Maybe (depending on your project structure) you could (like to see in your screenshot) enable the option to disable this specific exception in a specific assembly, but IMHO it is far easier to simply tick the exception checkbox globally when needed.